# Quartz JDBC Job Store not running jobs

Tags: java, spring, jdbc, quartz-scheduler

I have a quartz with Spring implementation that was working fine in a standalone environment that I'm now moving to a clustered environment.  I'm making use of the JDBC-backed job stores to coordinate Quartz.  For the life of me, I can't seem to make it work when I connect the database aspect of it.  To do the initial setup, I followed the instructions [here](http://www.objectpartners.com/2013/07/09/configuring-quartz-2-with-spring-in-clustered-mode/) and my application context looks like this:

```
<bean class="org.springframework.scheduling.quartz.SchedulerFactoryBean">
        <property name="configLocation" value="classpath:quartz.properties"/>
        <property name="dataSource" ref="dataSource"/>
        <property name="transactionManager" ref="txManager"/>


        <property name="schedulerName" value="ClusteredScheduler"/>


         <property name="overwriteExistingJobs" value="true"/>

        <property name="autoStartup" value="true"/>
        <property name="applicationContextSchedulerContextKey" value="applicationContext"/>
        <property name="jobFactory">
          <bean class="com.project.scheduling.persistence.AutowiringSpringBeanJobFactory"/>
        </property>
        <property name="jobDetails">
            <list>
                <ref bean="shipNoticeJob" />
                <ref bean="idleDeviceJob" />
                <ref bean="distanceJob" />
                <ref bean="deviceMaintenanceJob" />
            </list>
        </property>

        <property name="triggers">
            <list>
                <ref bean="shipNoticeCronTrigger" />
                <ref bean="idleDeviceTrigger" />
                <ref bean="distanceTrigger" />
                <ref bean="deviceMaintenanceTrigger" />

            </list>
        </property>
    </bean>
```

Where `AutowiringBeanFactory` is basically exactly the same as the one at the tutorial.

My `quartz.properties` file is here:

```
# Needed to manage cluster instances
org.quartz.scheduler.instanceId=AUTO
org.quartz.scheduler.instanceName=ClusteredScheduler
#
org.quartz.jobStore.useProperties=true
org.quartz.jobStore.tablePrefix = QRTZ_
org.quartz.jobStore.isClustered = true

# Change this to match your DB vendor
#org.quartz.jobStore.class = org.quartz.impl.jdbcjobstore.JobStoreTX
org.quartz.jobStore.driverDelegateClass = org.quartz.impl.jdbcjobstore.StdJDBCDelegate



org.quartz.scheduler.rmi.export = false
org.quartz.scheduler.rmi.proxy = false
org.quartz.threadPool.class = org.quartz.simpl.SimpleThreadPool
org.quartz.threadPool.threadCount = 10
org.quartz.threadPool.threadPriority = 5
org.quartz.threadPool.threadsInheritContextClassLoaderOfInitializingThread = true
org.quartz.scheduler.wrapJobExecutionInUserTransaction=true

#org.quartz.threadPool.threadCount = 3
#org.quartz.jobStore.class = org.quartz.simpl.RAMJobStore
```

I know that this file is on the classpath and included as changes to this file affect whether the jobs actually fire.  The last two lines of this file are the configuration I have used in the "standalone environment" that work perfectly.  Also, the current contents of the application context work when using the stand alone version.  (Obviously, some of the properties have no meaning given that they apply to a database-backed job store and not a RAM job store).

When I comment out all of the lines in the `quartz.properties` file aside from the last two, everything works as expected.  However, in the current implementation non of the jobs run and non of the triggers in the database ever fire.

Thoughts?

**Edit** Per the question about logging, I added

```
<logger name="org.quartz">
  <level value="trace"/>
  <appender-ref ref="file" />
```

and then when that produced no output, I tried

```
<category name="org.quartz">
  <priority value="trace"/>
  <appender-ref ref="file" />
```

Neither one produced ANY logging output...

Comment: If you turn up `org.quartz` to debug level in your logging, do you see any messages relating to jobs not firing?

Comment: @WillKeeling see my edits above.  I haven't been able to get quartz to log anything either...which is suspect...

Answer (score 0, accepted):

Finally figured this out.  The ultimate issue was that I was using a quartz 2.1.6 jar with the schema from 2.2.0.  That said, the bigger issue was that because Quartz uses SLF4j instead of Log4J of Commons Logging, I needed the SLF4j Log4J bindings jar on my classpath, which I didn't have.  As a result, all of the errors were getting swallowed because none of the logging statements made it to the log files.  Amazing what happens when you can see the error messages!